# Help me understand a consequence of continuity.

Tags: continuity

Let $f:[-\pi, \pi] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a Riemann-integrable function that is continuous at zero.

> Since $f$ is continuous at $0$, we can choose $0 \lt \delta \leq \pi/2$, so that $f(\theta) \gt f(0)/2$ whenever $|\theta| \lt \delta$.

I'm not seeing how they got that from continuity.

Comment: Do you really mean $f\colon [-\pi, \pi]\to \color{red}{\Bbb C}$? You may lose order.

Comment: In addition, you may exclude the case $f=0$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: In the definition of continuity, choose $\epsilon = f(0)/2$, then there exists $\delta$ so small that if $|\theta| < \delta$ then $|f(0) - f(\theta)| < f(0)/2$. Your statement follows from this.

Comment: The part I'm not getting is how you get $f(\theta) \gt f(0)/2$ from that.

Comment: I think I got it.  If $f(\theta) \leq f(0)/2$, then $f(0) - f(\theta) \geq f(0)/2$  Taking absolute value (and $f(0) \gt 0$ given), gives a contradiction so $f(\theta) \gt f(0)/2$. QED